# Как отобразить график без точек javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Как нарисовать график, используя linechart, единой линией без точек. Я пробовал данный метод

```
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series =  new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
    for (Double d:pointForDrowing()
         ) {

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(String.valueOf(d),function(d)));
    }
    chart.getData().add(series);
```

.И вот что получается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А хотелось бы так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что у вас не получилось? что вы попробовали?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0):

Мануал, [откуда взята нижняя картинка](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm), рекомендует использовать

```
lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```